# Unable to reference static files on nginx + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nginx, flask

I have my nginx conf file with the static file location set as:

```
# Settings to by-pass for static files
location ^~ /static/  {
    # Example:
    # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
    root /opt/flaskapp/static/;
}
```

My template file has this:

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/static/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Though, when I run my flask app - bootstrap isn't loading any of the js :(

I have tried multiple combinations of locations and even tried using this in my nginx con file:

```
location /bootstrap.min.js { 
    alias /opt/flaskapp/static/bootstrap.min.js; 
}
```

I can access the js file via 127.0.0.1/bootstrap.min.js.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: nginx service doesn't restart when I change it that way

Comment: ops, my mistake, your config actually is allowed as described here: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/basic-nginx-configuration

Comment: when its configured correct would i be able to retrieve static files via: 127.0.0.1/static/file_name.js?

Comment: I think you should remove the 'static/' from the `root` directive

Comment: Vinicius is correct. Nginx is looking for /opt/flaskapp/static/static/ you should be able to confirm this in your access logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you think that nginx will look for `/opt/flaskapp/static/<file>` in the filesystem while it looks at `/opt/flaskapp/static/static/<file>` because the URI is always appended to the local path (`root`) until you either :

- Use `rewrite` to change the URI.
- Map the location prefix or regex to a physical path using the `alias` directive.

So in your case you want the latter, and the right configuration is :

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    alias /opt/flaskapp/static/;
}
```

In your specific case, as the URI prefix is the same as the directory name, you can also simply change your local `root` to the parent directory (`root /opt/flaskapp`).